# Replace numbers of a certain substring in a string with Java

Tags: string, replace

I currently struggling trying to extract a certain substring of a string and replacing it's content. The digits to be exact. The numbers change, so I can not take the whole string. For example, I have a message like

```
String message = "hi John. You have two contracts listed: 
                  TV-70002548 and FV-50006578. The first contract 
                  ends on March 15th. I will pay you a final amount of 350 $."
```

In that String I have a set of different numbers, but I only want to extract the contract numbers and have them rewritten, like `TV-70002548` -> `TV-seven null null null two five four eight`.

I wrote a method that extracts all digits after `V-` because this character is unique for the contract numbers in a string:

```
   private String replaceContractNo(String pMessage, String pInput, String pOutput) {
        String contractno;
        contractno = pMessage.substring(pMessage.indexOf("V-")-2);
        return contractno.replaceAll(pInput, pOutput);
    }
```

Later I want to replace the digits with words, like:

```
replaceContractNo(pMainMessage,"0"," null")
replaceContractNo(pMainMessage,"1"," one")
```

This does not work, because the message gets written out each time. Is there an easy solution to this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

So this code may be kind of ugly but it works. I'm sure that you can clean it up, but it gets the job done (just make a new file and copy and paste it if you'd like, and if you can't find the better algorithm, let me know, and I'd be happy to help):

```
public class contract {

  public contract(){

  }
  public static String replaceContractNo(String pMessage, String pInput, String pOutput) {

      return pMessage.replaceAll(pInput, pOutput);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){

      contract myContract = new contract();

      String message = "hi John. You have two contracts listed: TV-70002548 and FV-50006578. The first contract ends on March 15th. I will pay you a final amount of 350 $.";

      int start1 = message.indexOf("TV");
      System.out.println(start1);
      int end1 = message.indexOf(' ', start1);
      System.out.println(end1);
      String str1 = message.substring(start1, end1);
      System.out.println(str1);

      String test1 = replaceContractNo(str1, "0", "null");
      System.out.println("test1 = "+test1);

      int start2 = message.indexOf("FV");
      int end2 = message.indexOf(' ', start2);
      String str2 = message.substring(start2, end2);

      String test2 = replaceContractNo(str2, "5", "five");
      System.out.println("test2 = " +test2);

      message = message.replaceAll(str1, test1);
      message = message.replaceAll(str2, test2);

      System.out.println(message);

        }

    }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. I found a solution similar to yours already. But thank you for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
str1.replaceAll(oldString, newString);
```

Comment: Hi, yes exactly!

Comment: Is policyNumber a global variable? Also, I don't see where you are using contractno at all in this function? I mean contractno is changed in the scope of the function but what is it really used for?

Comment: sorry, that was a spelling mistake. It should be contractno

Comment: I see. Can you show me what the string you would like to produce would look like?

Comment: When there is either TV-70002548 or FV-50006578 (or any other contract number) , I want to store the number "70002548" and "50006578" and rewrite them as "seven null null null  two five four eight" etc.

Comment: You mean you are getting the full string after TV/FV right? Including the "first contract...[....]"

Comment: If so, I think it should look like this instead:
`contractno = pMessage.substring(pMessage.indexOf("V-")-2, pMessage.indexOf(' ', pMessage.indexOf("V-"));`

Comment: Yes, I get the full string, stored in message. I have no control over the contract numbers I get. But I need to replace every digit of a contract number, with its name, meanwhile ignoring other numbers in the message.

Comment: Well that substring does so if you add the ending index parameter as I did. You should use the replaceAll method on the original string after extracting the replaced string.

Comment: When I get time later today, I’ll send you the code that works